# Synchronize transition effects between two q-cards

Tags: vue.js, quasar

A module in my app has two q-cards: one on the left and the other on the right.

The first q-card can be collapsed / hidden by the action of a button, with a transition effect, being very similar to the behavior of the q-drawer.

This part works well.

The problem is in the resizing of the q-card on the right, it causes a delay and then it resizes abruptly.

[CODE PEN](https://codepen.io/ijose/full/RwGRGxe)

```
<div id="q-app">
  <div class="fit row no-wrap justify-start items-stretch content-stretch">
     

        <transition
             enter-active-class="animated slideInLeft"
             leave-active-class="animated slideOutLeft"
            >
            <q-card 
              v-if="leftVisible"
              class="col-3  window-height" 
              style="margin:1px; box-shadow: 5px 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.22); z-index:100" >
                
                <q-toolbar class="shadow-1"  style="max-height:20px; margin-left:2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF; font-size:10px">                    Test
                </q-toolbar>
              </q-card>

      </transition>
      
     <q-card class="fit window-height bg-white" >
       <q-toolbar class="shadow-1"  style="max-height:20px; margin-left:2px; border-bottom: 1px solid #CFCFCF; font-size:10px">           
              <q-btn icon="menu" color="blue-9" flat rounded dense @click.stop="leftVisible = !leftVisible"/>               
        </q-toolbar>
     </q-card>

 </div>
  
      </q-page>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your cards inside the transition tag, that way it's going to be animated smoothly. But when I tried to do that it broke your layout, cause you cannot have wrapper `row` class in that case. So you need to figure out the way to align your items within the `transition` tag. One of the options is to give fixed width to your left card, and the other should have dynamic with in percents. Also, take a look at [transition modes](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Modes) in order to find a desirable effects.

Comment: Thanks David Go. Despite several attempts, some including your suggestions, I still haven't found a solution that works.